# How does loading view of a tableview cell from xib differ from dequereusablecellwithidentifier method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two tables in two different view controllers. At some point both the tables might have same type of cells. As both these tables are in different view controllers I will have to have two different cells in both the tables yet containing the same type of data if I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method to obtain the cell.

On the other hand if I use a xib for the view of `tableViewCell`, I can reuse it in both the controllers.

I know that using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` gives me performance advantage. I want to know how performance is affected when I use a `xib` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display a table view, every cell is loaded when it's about to be displayed. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` allows you to take a cell that just got out of the screen and use it again for the one that will appear next. It's like recycling garbages.

This is how it works:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     ...
     [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibname" 
                                       bundle:nil] 
 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuse"];
}  

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Starting from iOS 5, the following will either dequeue an existing cell or instantiate a new one from xib
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuse";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

If you don't reuse your cells, you will have serious performance issues on big table view.

But **you can't "reuse" cells across different tableviews**. you have to implement the previous method for both of them.

Comment: How will initWithStyle create view for cell from an xib?

Answer (score 0):

**Refer This** : For maximum performance, a table view’s data source should generally reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. A table view maintains a queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has marked for reuse.
What happens if you don’t use a **reuseIdentifier**?
If you don’t, your table view will configure a brand-new cell each time a row is displayed. This is an expensive operation and will definitely affect the scrolling performance of your app.
Since the introduction of iOS 6, you’re expected to use reuseIdentifiers for header and footer views, as well as UICollectionView’s cells and supplementary views.
To use reuseIdentifiers, call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the table view:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available, or creates a new one if necessary using the previously registered nib file or class. If no cell is available for reuse, and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.